# In JavaBean, does the file always recognize the first name of property as uppercase?

Tags: java, jsp

The following code is in the .jsp file I have.

```
<jsp:useBean id="entry" class="coreservlets.SaleEntry" />

<jsp:setProperty
    name="entry"
    property="itemID"<%--WHY IS THIS ONE itemID, NOT ItemID?--%>
    value='<%= request.getParameter("itemID") %>' />
```

And this one is a part of `SaleEntry.java` in proper package folder:

```
public void setItemID(String itemID) {//This one is 'ItemID'
    if (itemID != null) {
        this.itemID = itemID;
    } else {
        this.itemID = "unknown";
    }
}
```

What I'm wondering is why the `property` in `jsp:setProperty` block is `itemID`, not `ItemID`. Of course this code works without any problem.

Does .jsp file always automatically change the first letter of `property` attribute in `set-` and `get-` block to uppercase?

Answer (score 0):

It always be lower case the first letter in JSP if  is a method of get and set Ex:

> ```
> The standar format of a bean requires that the names of the accesor/mutator pair have a fixed syntax.
> 1. The mutator will be of the form setXxx
> 2. The accesor will be of the form getXxx
> 3. set and get are in lowercase
> 4. the first letter after set or get is uppercase. All leters after that can be uppercase or lowercase
> ```

From

> Guide to Web Development with Java: Understanding Website Creation

And the element in JSP will be always in lowerCase

```
Element Name  -  Accesor Name -  Mutator Name
name="hobby"     getHobby         setHobby
```